# KQL Query to get number of instances in VMSS

Tags: azure, kql

I'm trying to create a query that gives me the number of instances running in Azure from scale sets.

I need to configure an alert for monitoring when the number of instances drops below 2 VMs. Unless anyone knows how to monitor VM Scale sets, how do you track heartbeat when you have VMs scaling up and down.

I have tried in Resource Graph Explorer and they're available under :

```
Resources
    | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets'
    | where name contains "-conto"
    | join kind=inner (ResourceContainers | where type=='microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project SubName=name, subscriptionId) on subscriptionId
    | project VMMSName = name, RGName = resourceGroup, VMMSSKU = sku.name, VMMSCount = sku.capacity, SubName, SubID = subscriptionId
```

But I can't use the same query in Log analytics. When I do a query in log anaytics, which has the option to create an alert I don't get numbe rof instances, and I need to have a way to monitor the VMs.

```
Heartbeat
| where ResourceType contains "virtualmachinescaleset"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now as per the **[MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftcomputevirtualmachinescalesets)** we don't have any metrics to get the **no. of VM Scale set instances down/up**.

We can get the VM Scale Sets Performance metrics like (CPU/Disk/Memory/etc.,)

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67231490/15997690) for more information

Thanks @[hey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69274493/15997690) for the workaround which you have provided.

#### Workaround:

Install the **Azure Monitor Agent** in your all VM Scale Set.

Azure Monitor Agent will send the **heartbeat** by default. It will be added in an **Azure Monitor**.

**Query to get no of VM Scale Set instances from heartbeats.**

> ```
> InsightsMetrics 
> | where Namespace == "Computer" 
> | where Origin =="vm.azm.ms/map" 
> | where Name == "Heartbeat" 
> | summarize Hb_count = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 10m), Computer 
> | extend alive=iff(Hb_count > 2, 1.0, 0.0) //computer considered "down" if it has 2 or fewer heartbeats in 10 min interval 
> | where alive == true 
> | project TimeGenerated, alive, Computer 
> | summarize Hb_alive_count = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 10m), alive 
> | project TimeGenerated, Hb_alive_count 
> | render timechart
> ```